# How to access global typescript variable from anonymous function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 application and I want to perform some logic when the user closes the browser window. I am using **beforeunload** event of the browser window. I have placed the following code in my TypeScript class constructor:

```
export class MyAngularComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {  

  callServer()
  {
     //Logic to call the server
  }

  constructor(private updateServiceFactory: UpdateService) {

    window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
      this.callServer();  //this does not work            
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the compile error in the line this.callServer(). The error says "Property 'callServer' does not exist on type 'Window'". I understand that "this" in the context of the anonymous function refers to the Window object.

Question: how do I call callServer() method from inside of the anonymous function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an arrow function instead of a simple function. Arrow functions capture this from the declaring context.

```
export class MyAngularComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {  

  callServer()
  {
     //Logic to call the server
  }

  constructor(private updateServiceFactory: UpdateService) {

    window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
      this.callServer();  //this now refers to MyAngularComponent             
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone care to comment why they down voted? Want to know what the problem is maybe I can fix it :)

Comment: My answer and the question were also downvoted, so I suspect someone just went through and blindly downvoted everything for some reason (the other answers hadn't been posted yet).

Comment: @Diopside has a point, if angular provides a way to listen for host events it is best to use that :)

Comment: it sees this, but I cannot make it see other variable defiuned before anonimous function. WIth php I just use use keyword  and it is simple. How can it be so complicated in typescript?

Answer (score 4):

Try using HostListener in your component, and not in the constructor.

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
 doSomething($event) {
     // your code here //
 }
```

The constructor is usually not a good place to do anything other than stuff directly related to parameters passed into the constructor.

Comment: This works as well as the accepted answer, but Titan was first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind` to change the function's `this` to the correct context.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  this.callServer();
}.bind(this)
```

Comment: This works as well as the accepted answer, but Titan was first.